# Magento backend 404 error due to disabling default store view

Tags: magento

I have a working magento installation with 2 websites 2 stores and 2 views the first one being default other i created just for some testing (which giving 404 error for some reason).

So it happened that while i was fiddling with magento's 'manage store' feature i accidental disabled the default store view and on refresh i got nothing but a 404 error on the frontend as well as on the backend .I can't access any of the admin feature so undo it  , any idea how to fix it ?.I am using magento 1.9.0.1

Comment: Which 404 page? http://alanstorm.com/magentos_many_404_pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your database, navigate to the table `core_store`.
Then look at the list of the records and reset the field `is_active` for the right store at the value **1**.

Or if you are sure there is no stores that should stay disabled just run

```
update `core_store` set `is_active` = 1
```

If that does not solve the issue, also manually clean your caches : on the server or via ftp or ssh : delete the entire content of the folder `var/cache`